# Define a relationship() that is only true sometimes

Tags: sqlalchemy

I'm working with a database schema that has a relationship that isn't always true, and I'm not sure how to describe it with sqlalchemy's ORM.

All the primary keys in this database are stored as a blob type, and are 16 byte binary strings.

I have a table called `attribute`, and this table has a column called `data_type`.  There are a number of built in `data_type`s, that are not defined explicitly in the database.  So, maybe a `data_type` of `00` means it is a string, and `01` means it is a float, etc (those are hex values).  The highest value for the built in data types is `12` (18 in decimal).

However, for some rows in `attribute`, the value of the attribute stored in the row must exist in a pre-defined list of values.  In this case, `data_type` referrs to `lookup.lookup_id`.  The actual data type for the attribute can then be retrieved from `lookup.data_type`.

I'd like to be able to call just `Attribue.data_type` and get back 'string' or 'number'.  Obviously I'd need to define the `{0x00: 'string', 0x01: 'number'}` mapping somewhere, but how can I tell sqlalchemy that I want `lookup.data_type` if the value of `attribute.data_type` is greater than 18?

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways to do this.

1. The simplest, by far, is to just put your predefined data types into the table `lookup`. You say that you "need to define the... mapping somewhere", and a table is as good a place as any.
2. Assuming that you can't do that, the next simplest thing is to create a python `property` on class Attribute. The only problem will be that you can't query against it. You'll want to reassign the column `data_type` so that it maps to `_data_type`:

   ```
   data_type_dict = {0x00: 'string',
                     0x01: 'number,
                     ...}

   class Attribute(Base):

       __tablename__ = 'attribute'


       _data_type = Column('data_type')

       ...

       @property
       def data_type(self):
           dt = data_type_dict.get(self._data_type, None)
           if dt is None:
               s = Session.object_session(self)
               lookup = s.query(Lookup).filter_by(id=self._data_type).one()
               dt = lookup.data_type
           return dt
   ```
3. If you want this to be queryable, that is, if you want to be able to do `session.query(Attribute).filter_by(data_type='string')`, you need to map data_type to something the database can handle, i.e., an SQL statement. You could do this in raw SQL as a `CASE` expression:

   ```
   from sqlalchemy.sql.expression import select, case

   class Attribute(Base):

       ...

       data_type = column_property(select([attribute, lookup])\
                                   .where(attribute.data_type==lookup.lookup_id)\
                                   .where(case([(attribute.data_type==0x00, 'string'),
                                                (attribute.data_type==0x01, 'number'),
                                                ...],
                                               else_=lookup.data_type))
   ```

   I'm not 100% certain that last part will work; you may need to explicitly join the tables `attribute` and `lookup` to specify that it's an outer join, though I *think* SQLAlchemy does that by default. The downside of this approach is that you are always going to try to join with the table `lookup`, though to query using SQL, you sort of have to do that.
4. The final option is to use a polymorphism, and map the two cases (data_type greater/less than 18) to two different subclasses:

   ```
   class Attribute(Base):
       __tablename__ = 'attribute'

       _data_type = Column('data_type')
       _lookup = column_property(attribute.data_type > 18)
       __mapper_args__ = {'polymorphic_on': _lookup}

   class FixedAttribute(Attribute):

       __mapper_args__ = {'polymorphic_identity': 0}

       data_type = column_property(select([attribute.data_type])\
                                   .where(case([(attribute.data_type==0x00, 'string'),
                                                (attribute.data_type==0x01, 'number'),
                                                ...])))

   class LookupAttribute(Attribute):

       __mapper_args__ = {'polymorphic_identity': 1}

       data_type = column_property(select([lookup.data_type],
                                      whereclause=attribute.data_type==lookup.lookup_id))
   ```

   You might have to replace the `'polymorphic_on': _lookup` with an explicit `attribute.data_type > 18`, depending on when that `ColumnProperty` gets bound.

As you can see, these are all really messy. Do #1 if it's at all possible.